# MVC jQuery autocomplete - unable to grab url in select event for clickable links

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm making an ajax call to an MVC controller. It returns a JsonResponse for the jQuery autocomplete to use. In the "source" section of the autocomplete, I'm able to access the properties fine from the JSON. **The dropdown works fine.**

But when it comes to using select event, the ui variable shows the same value for "label" and "value". Which is the value of displayText (see code below). The documentation suggests that I should be able to access my URL property by doing "ui.item.url" in the select event

I want to be able to grab the URL that I'm passing from my controller in the select event.

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AutocompleteAndSuggest(string term)
{

    // Create an empty list.
    var results = new List<ServiceProviderResults>();


    for (int i = 0; i < suggestResult.Results.Count; i++)
    {
        // Now add the suggestions.
        results.Add(new ServiceProviderResults { url = $"DYNAMIC URL HERE", displayText = $"{suggestResult.Results[i].Document.companyname} ({suggestResult.Results[i].Document.serviceproviderid})" });
    }

    // Return the list.
    return new JsonResult(results);
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 2,
  position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left-23 bottom+10"
  },
  source: function(request, response) {
    var controllerUrl = "/Home/AutoCompleteAndSuggest?term=" + $("#autocomplete").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: controllerUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {

          // Show the autocomplete suggestion.
          document.getElementById("underneath").innerHTML = data[0].displayText;

          // Remove the top suggestion as it is used for inline autocomplete.
          var array = new Array();
          for (var n = 1; n < data.length; n++) {
            array[n - 1] = data[n].displayText;
          }

          // Show the drop-down list of suggestions.
          response(array);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("underneath").innerHTML = "";
        }
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui); // ui.item has "label" and "value", both are equal to displayText
    window.location.href = ui.item.url
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did with autocomplete and its working fine for me:

JS code:

```
let arrivalId = [];
fetch(arrivalUrl).then(
    response => response.json()
).then(data => {
    if (dataIsValid(data)) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(
            arrivalId,
            JSON.parse(data.data)
        );
    }
});

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: (request, response) => {
        var results;
        var aData = $.map(arrivalId, (value, key) => {
            return {
                label: value.Value,
                value: value.Key
            };
        });
        results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(aData, request.term);
        response(results);
    },
    select: (event, ui) => {
        $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
```